# Como expor um método como bean para usar a injeção de dependências do spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Preciso expor um método como um bean no `ApplicationContext` do Spring para utilizá-lo na injeção de um atributo, que possui mais de uma implementação. O que eu fiz foi o seguinte:

1. Adicionei o método que irá criar meu objeto utilizando a anotação `@Bean`:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Bean
   public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
       return CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
   }

   [...]

   }
   ```
2. Adicionei o `@Autowired` para injetar o atributo que possui o tipo da interface `CsrfTokenRepository` que é retornada pelo método que eu expus como bean do Spring:

   ```
   public final class RestClient<T> {
   private Class<T> type;
   @Autowired
   private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository;

   [...]

   }
   ```
3. Quando eu tento usar o atributo, ocorre NPE porque ele não foi injetado pelo Spring:

   ```
   public final class RestClient<T> {
   private Class<T> type;
   @Autowired
   private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository;

   public HttpHeaders csrfHeaders() throws IOException {
       CsrfToken csrfToken = csrfTokenRepository.generateToken(null); //Aqui ocorre o NPE!
       HttpHeaders headers = createHeaders();
       headers.add(csrfToken.getHeaderName(), csrfToken.getToken());
       headers.add("Cookie", "XSRF-TOKEN=" + csrfToken.getToken());
       return headers;
   }
   }
   ```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at br.com.restclientjersey.RestClient.csrfHeaders(RestClient.java:61)
>       at br.com.restclientjersey.RestClient.postCall(RestClient.java:47)
>       at br.com.restclientjersey.RestClientTest.testPostCallStatus200(RestClientTest.java:83)

Ainda assim o atributo não é injetado. Eu até tentei adicionar um `Qualifier` mas ainda assim não funciona. O que falta fazer para poder injetar esse atributo chamando o método `csrfTokenRepository`?

Comment: Algum erro ou exception?

Comment: NullPointerException ao tentar usar o atributo injetado, vou adicionar na pergunta.

Comment: Você já experimentou criar uma classe à parte, usando alguma anotação de bean (@Repository etc.) para ver se funciona ou não é uma opção?

Comment: O problema é replicar a implementação adicionando mais um nível de herança. Por isso queria algo mais elegante, como injetar um método como construtor. Assim evito criar uma classe "wrapper" só pra isso.

Comment: Sua classe `CsrfTokenRepository ` está anotada para ser um bean (@Component, @Repository etc.) também?

Comment: Esse CsrfTokenRepository é uma interface do Spring, então lá ele declara.

Comment: Como a instância de `RestClient` é criada? O pacote `br.com.restclientjersey` é "scaneado" pelo Spring? Obs.: não existe "método como bean", o _bean_ é o retorno do método, é isto que é gerenciado pelo Spring como _bean_.

Comment: Encontrei o problema, @BrunoCésar. O que ocorria é que nos testes o RestClient era criado com new e não injetado. Quando eu injetei no teste ele conseguiu carregar a dependência! Obrigada.

Comment: Legal, era o que havia imaginado mesmo quando questionei sobre como a instância era criada ;)

Comment: @BrunoCésar, como ajudou, sugiro incluir sua resposta (descoberta nos comentários) para a pergunta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu erro mostra que a classe `RestClient` não conseguiu obter o Bean do Spring para fazer a injeção da dependência de `csrfTokenRepository`.

Como você não mostrou como está usando a classe `RestClient` e ela não está marcada com nenhum estereótipo do Spring (`@Component`, `@Service` ou `@Repository`), então o problema pode estar na forma como está instanciando ela.

Para o Spring fazer a injeção de dependência do `csrfTokenRepository`, a classe na qual está pedindo esta injeção também precisa ser controlada pelo Spring. Ou seja, ela também precisa estar injetada na classe na qual está sendo utilizada.

Imaginando que você tem uma classe `CrsftTokenService`, esta seria a forma **correta** de usar `RestClient`, a injetando com `@Autowired`:

```
@Service
class CrsftTokenService {
    @Autowired
    private RestClient restClient;

    public void call() {
        restClient.csrfHeaders();
    }
}
```

E esta seria a forma **incorreta**, a injeção de dependência não irá funcionar:

```
@Service
class CrsftTokenService {
    public void call() {
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
        restClient.csrfHeaders();
    }
}
```

E lembrando novamente que sua classe `RestClient` precisa ter algum estereótipo do Spring para ser injetável em outras classes.